# Netty logs now show "low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably"

Tags: java, netty

Why from netty 4.0.15 to 4.0.19 am I now seeing "Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably." in the logs?

I'm not an Android platform and my JRE hasn't changed and I'm using OSGi.

Did something change order wise as to how to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

PlatformDependent0 appears to have changed how it detects if sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer is available.

```
    boolean directBufferFreeable = false;
    try {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer", false, getClassLoader(PlatformDependent0.class));
        Method method = cls.getMethod("cleaner");
        if ("sun.misc.Cleaner".equals(method.getReturnType().getName())) {
            directBufferFreeable = true;
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // We don't have sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner().
    }
    logger.debug("sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner(): {}", directBufferFreeable? "available" : "unavailable");
```

Since this is an OSGi application I needed to add "sun.nio.ch" to the ClassLoader. I'm using felix in this case and added to the config the following properties:

```
config.put(FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA, "sun.misc,sun.nio.ch");
```